# IP Range to CIDR in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ip, ip-address, cidr

I want to do two things: Convert IP Address inputs into CIDR 
Here are some example inputs:

```
1.1.1.1    
192.168.*.* #=> 192.168.0-255.0-255
192.168.1.2-20
1.1.1-10.1-100
```

Check if a given IP Address falls into any CIDR. This must be a very fast query, as it's a very common lookup in my web app. I'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
def matches?(request)
  valid = @ips.select {|cidr| cidr.contains?(request.remote_ip) }
  !valid.empty?
end
```

I think converting IP ranges into CIDR will let lookups be faster than what we're doing now, which is breaking the IP's into integer octets. We then index the first two sets of octets to partially match against IP's. Another option might be converting everything to ints and doing comparisons that way. I'd convert to ints with something like this `IPAddr.new("1.1.1.1").to_i` but then I'd need to store an upper and lower IP for each range instead of just a single CIDR.

Please let me know if I am overlooking any mainstream approaches, popular gems or repo's. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, to get the CIDR notation of a range, you need an IP and the number of network bits (calculated from the netmask).

To enumerate the addresses of a given range, you can use the `NetAddr` (< 2.x) gem.

```
p NetAddr::CIDR.create('192.168.1.0/24').enumerate
  => ['192.168.1.0', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2'... '192.168.1.255']
```

You can also calculate the bits from the netmask on the fly:

```
mask_int = NetAddr.netmask_to_i('255.255.255.0')
p NetAddr.mask_to_bits(mask_int)
  => 24
```

And to create a range based on two IPs:

```
lower = NetAddr::CIDR.create('192.168.1.1')
upper = NetAddr::CIDR.create('192.168.1.10')
p NetAddr.range(lower, upper)
  => ['192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3'... '192.168.1.9']
```

So now that you can create a CIDR range, you can check to see if an IP is a part of it:

```
cidr = NetAddr::CIDR.create('192.168.1.0/24')
p cidr.contains?('192.168.1.10')
  => true
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up converting everything to int's, indexing the upper and lower ip ranges as ints to do really fast comparisons. Your tip to use the NetAddr helped get me to the right direction. The issue with our environment is that user inputs of specific ip ranges and wildcards would make CIDR lookup much more complicated than I initially thought.

Comment: converting a range to single ips is ofc "converting to CIDR (blocks)", but not very efficient.

Comment: I understand, that too much time has passed, but please be careful with `NetAddr.range`. This method creates an Array, so if you will try to create range for `/8` netmask, for example, it will create an array with **16777214 items**, which is not efficient and will cost extra memory for your application. Instead, I recommend you to use following construction: `range = lower..upper`. This will create Range object and allow you to check if CIDR is in range, like this: `cidr = NetAddr::CIDR.create('192.168.1.0/24'); range.cover?(cidr)`

Answer (score 10):

I suspect everything you need is in IPAddr.  I use this to see if the remote IP is coming from a private network:

```
['127.0.0.0/8', '10.0.0.0/8', '172.16.0.0/12', '192.168.0.0/16', '192.168.10.0/8'
].none?{|block| IPAddr.new(block) === request.remote_ip}
```

Comment: Just remember to `require 'ipaddr'` before using it.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but it seems that one aspect of this question has not been addressed, that is, converting a range of ip addresses to one or more CIDR entries.

I use the following approach to lookup suspicious ip activity on my firewall, and if it is in a country that I'm not interested in allowing access (you know who you are) I use whois to lookup the address range, and then calculate the merged CIDRs as follows,

```
whois xxx.yyy.zzz.123
# find address range for this ip
range="xxx.yyy.zzz.0-xxx.yyy.zzz.255".split(/\s*-\s*/)
lower=range[0]
upper=range[1]
ip_net_range = NetAddr.range(lower, upper, :Inclusive => true, :Objectify => true)  
cidrs = NetAddr.merge(ip_net_range, :Objectify => true)
```

This is a example on an internal network, but it is trivial to extend to a public ip block,

```
whois 192.168.1.3
range="192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255".split(/\s*-\s*/)
upper=range[0]
lower=range[1]
ip_net_range = NetAddr.range(lower, upper, :Inclusive => true, :Objectify => true)
cidrs = NetAddr.merge(ip_net_range, :Objectify => true)
p cidrs
[192.168.0.0/16]
```

Then I can pass that CIDR to my firewall software (shorewall) to have it dynamically drop that cidr(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NetAddr (> 2.x.x) gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/netaddr/).

Use parse class method to create a IPv4Net object from its string representation. It will default is a /32 netmask if not specified.

```
private_ips = NetAddr::IPv4Net.parse('192.168.0.0/16')
```

Now you use rel method to determine the relationship with another IPv4Net object.
For example, if we would like to know if '2.3.4.5/31' is part of `private_ips`

```
private_ips.rel(NetAddr::IPv4Net.parse('2.3.4.5/31')).eql?(1) || private_ips.rel(NetAddr::IPv4Net.parse('2.3.4.5/31')).eql?(0)
=> false

private_ips.rel(NetAddr::IPv4Net.parse('192.168.0.0/31')).eql?(1) || private_ips.rel(NetAddr::IPv4Net.parse('192.168.0.0/31')).eql?(0)
=> true
```

Note: rel method determines the relationship to another IPv4Net.
Returns:

- 1 if this IPv4Net is the supernet of other.
- 0 if the two are equal.
- -1 if this IPv4Net is a subnet of other.
- nil if the networks are unrelated.

[Gem Documentation Link](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/netaddr/2.0.3/NetAddr)