# How to convert IP range to a single CIDR using Ruby

Tags: ruby, ip, cidr

Does Ruby have a simple way to convert a range of IP addresses to CIDR?

I know in Python we can do it like this:

```
cidr = netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs(startip, endip)
```

I've looked to other questions here at StackOverflow and none of them are about converting a range of IP addresses to a **single** CIDR, like:

```
startip = '250.154.64.0'
endip = '250.154.64.255'

output: '250.154.64.0/24'
```

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406603/ip-range-to-cidr-in-ruby-rails

Comment: Thank you @VishwasNahar, however in that question they don't convert a range of IP addresses to a single CIDR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

```
require 'netaddr'

startip = '250.154.64.0'
endip = '250.154.64.255'

ip_net_range = NetAddr.range(startip, endip, :Inclusive => true, :Objectify => true)
cidrs = NetAddr.merge(ip_net_range, :Objectify => true)

puts cidrs
```

output: `250.154.64.0/24`